# Prevent flash messages from moving below container down

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, alert

I build a web application with `Bootstrap 4`. The user is notified with `alerts`. I followed the guidelines [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/#dismissing).

Unfortunately, the content below the alert moves down when an `alert` is shown and up, after the alert is dismissed. The `alert` should just flow over the content and not move it.

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    My alert message
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <h1>My title</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of the ways...

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container alert-container">
        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            My alert message
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>My title</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.alert-container {
  position: relative;
}

.alert {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Notice I added the class `alert-container` to the first container (you may use another class name if you want).

Comment: Your solution prevents the content from moving down. However, now the container does not span the entire width (see [here](https://imgur.com/a/SoTKXzo))

Comment: How does the layout look before? Can you share the screenshot too?

Comment: The initial look was like [this](https://imgur.com/a/h5bTizH). The alert moves the content (i.e. Login) down.

Comment: You can add `width: 100%;` to the `.alert` css